# Laravel throws "Memory Size Exhausted" error on usage of get() or all() eloquent methods

Tags: php, laravel

Please Laravel throws "Memory Size Exhausted" error on usage of get() or all() eloquent methods whether there are values in the db or not. But it gives expected result when I use the first() method. This is unsusual. Who can help?

E.g This

```
$transaction_history = Form::all(); // Produces the error
dd($transaction_history);
```

or this

```
$transaction_history = Form::get(); // Produces the error
dd($transaction_history);
```

It's expected to product either null for no result or a collection of objects!

But this

```
   $transaction_history = Form::first(); // Works fine
```

Comment: This will depend on how many rows you are selecting in the query. If you want `->all()` and the query returned 10 to 100 rows that fine, but if it returns 1,000,000 rows you are going to blow your memory limit

Comment: You can use this func to increase memory limit before getting data from DataBase ->  ini_set(‘memory_limit’,’256MB’); or greater than '256'

Comment: @RiggsFolly, yes that's true but it shows that memory error even for 1 or no rows in the database

Comment: @DejavuGuy, but I don't really need/want to increase the memory limit. Afterall, it has been working well before now and even some other places where I used that method doesn't return any error yet.

Answer (score 1):

what about receive first 100 rows and don't ruin your memory?

```
$transaction_history = Form::first(function ($value, $key) {
    return $key < 99;
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Thanks all, I guess I had to restart my server. But before I did that, I increased the memory_limit in the php.ini file to 256MB, restarted the server and it worked. I then reverted the limit to 128MB, restarted the server and it still works. Perhaps all I had to do was restart the server.

Comment: Optimize your application, don't increase memory limit, this is the worst solution you could come up with.

Comment: Like I said, I only needed to restart my server and it worked. I was never with the idea of increasing memory limit, I only did that to check if the error still pops up which didn't and I had to revert back to the previous settings and then restarted my server. Which made it work